# Deployment of ASP.NET MVC3 application on IIS V6 is not directing to the desired controller action

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, iis-6

In VS2010 ,I published my asp.net mvc3 web application as a file system and on IIS Manager, I created a new virtual directory(file system) and created a new website. But browsing the website is not redirecting me to the desired controller action. Can anyone suggest where i am going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

IIS6 doesn't support extensionless urls by default. You will have to configure a wildcard mapping if you want to use such urls. Otherwise you will need to modify your routing in order to append an extension in all your urls that is associated with the aspnet_isapi filter in IIS.

Here's a guide that you may checkout: [ASP.NET MVC 3 Extensionless URLs on IIS 6](http://haacked.com/archive/2010/12/22/asp-net-mvc-3-extensionless-urls-on-iis-6.aspx)

Comment: Hello Sir, I tried this methodology too. but didnt succeed. I will try to do it on IIS 7